# VMPlayer error "Network bridge on device vmnet0 is not working"

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vmware-player, windows-10-v1703

On a Windows 10 host, I have been using VMPlayer, which runs a guest Linux OS.  I have been using it for quite a while.

I applied some Windows updates a couple of days ago, which included the new Creator version.

Yesterday,
when I started my VMPlayer VM machine, I received the error

```
Network bridge on device vmnet0 is not working
```

Somehow I think
the Ethernet adapter settings were changed. 
I searched the web and found some hits on this which included
step by step instructions on how to install  the service – VMware Bridge Protocol under Settings, Network & Internet,
Ethernet.

The steps are straightforward and I'm sure I didn't make a mistake. I then stopped and restarted the
VMware  NAT and DHCP  services. I then rebooted my laptop. I received the same error when I started my VMPlayer VM machine.

I don't have Workstation installed. Basically I'm accessing a Teradata database which runs on a VM guest Linux machine under VMPlayer.

I'm hoping some Windows / VMware users may have seen this issue and may provide me with some advice... 
I'm stuck now and not sure how to proceed with this issue.

I hope that I will not have to reinstall VMware since that will require a massive amount of work for me.

My environment/configuration:

- Windows 10 Pro
- version 1703 build 15063.403
- My VMPlayer version is 6.0.7; I do not have Workstation installed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I searched for Windows 10 updates and found this KB. It corrected my VMware Player Ethernet - VMNET0 connection issue. I haven't read the KB yet but it applies changes to V1703..

2017-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 1703 for x64-based Systems (KB4022716)